# Angular: Prevent DomSanizer from updating on DOM Events

Tags: angular, iframe, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm facing an issue with `DomSanitizer`.

I've created a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjcxtd) that replicate this issue.

Every time the button is clicked, the iframe A is reloaded. The button does absolutely nothing - so it is not related to the iframe.

iframe A has a dynamic reference to its source. To make this work I use the `DomSanitizer`.

iframe B has a static reference and no reload here - whats I expected.
Just to show it is related to the sanitizer.

So I need to have an iframe in my application and its content should depend on the status of the application(some input). If that changes then a reload would be ok.

But I can not accept a reload by every button-click that has no connection to the iframe.

How can I handle that? Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Problem:

The problem is caused because you've used a `method` in the data-binding syntax, here:

```
<iframe 
  [src]="getURL()" 
  width="100%" 
  height="100px">
</iframe>
```

Because of this, every time Angular performs Change Detection, the `getURL` will get called.

#### The solution:

You can create a `Pipe` to sanitize the `iframe` `src` url. I've done something similar in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382743/2622292).

That way, your `iframe` won't reload every time Angular performs Change Detection.

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dom-sanitization-eg?file=src/app/safe.pipe.ts) for your ref.